# Configure SpringIO MultiPartFile Too Large Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Configuring a Spring.IO REST service with the following prevent file uploads greater than 1MB:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class UploadConfig {

    @Bean
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("1024KB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("1024KB");
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }
}
```

This works well for all uploads that are within this threshold. I would like to customize the response if the file is too large but and have not been able to determine how. At the moment a standard 401 response is returned.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to configure in Spring MVC a handler for `MultipartException`. If you only upload files in one or a few controllers, you can simply add an ExceptionHandler annotated method in those controllers :

```
@ExceptionHandler(MultipartException) {
public ModelAndView multipartException(MultipartException exception, ...) {
    // do you stuff
    // and return a ModelAndView ...
}
```

If you would have to add it in multiple controller, you can also register a custom `MultipartExceptionResolver` in servlet application context that will be fired for any Exception in Spring `DispatcherServlet`.

```
public class MultipartExceptionResolver  implements HandlerExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof MultipartException) {
            // do you stuff
            // and return a ModelAndView ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however your first suggestion does not appear to correctly resolve to any imports (exluding the erronerous { on line 1. For the second suggestion I am unsure how to connect this resolver to the application. For ref I am using java configuration options only.